# Parsing large XML file with lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am trying to parse the dblp.xml file(3.2gb) using lxml.
The following below is my code.

```
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO, BytesIO
tree = etree.parse("dblp.xml")
```

However I get an error stating :

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-6a342013a160> in <module>
      1 from lxml import etree
      2 from io import StringIO, BytesIO
----> 3 tree = etree.parse("dblp.xml")

src/lxml/etree.pyx in lxml.etree.parse()

src/lxml/parser.pxi in lxml.etree._parseDocument()

src/lxml/parser.pxi in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL()

src/lxml/parser.pxi in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile()

src/lxml/parser.pxi in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile()

src/lxml/parser.pxi in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc()

src/lxml/parser.pxi in lxml.etree._handleParseResult()

src/lxml/parser.pxi in lxml.etree._raiseParseError()

OSError: Error reading file 'dblp.xml': failed to load external entity "dblp.xml"
```

Both dblp.xml and dblp.dtd is in the root folder already.

Please help!

Comment: Is the path to `dblp.xml` correct? You might want to use a full path to be sure.

Comment: Try *etree.parse('/dblp.xml')* as it's in the root directory

Comment: The OSError indicates that dblp.xml is not in IPython's current working directory. If you get that sorted, it is likely that you will run into memory problems since the file is very large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`etree.iterparse`](https://lxml.de/3.2/parsing.html#iterparse-and-iterwalk) to avoid loading the whole file in memory:

```
events = ("start", "end")
with open("dblp.xml", "r") as fo:
    context = etree.iterparse(fo, events=events)
    for action, elem in context:
        # Do something
```

This will allow you to only extract entities you need while ignoring others.

Answer (score 1):

As Jan Jaap Meijerink stated, you may try to use iterparse. Possibly you could also disable lxml security features preventing parsing huge files (see documentation at https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.XMLParser-class.html):

```
with open('', 'r') as fobj:
    for event, elem in  etree.iterparse(
                    fobj,
                    huge_tree=True,
                ):
            #do something with element or event
```

Eventually, if you prefer trying use of parse, you may define xml parser with huge_tree enabled and set it as default for further usages of etree.parse:

```
xml_parser_settings = dict(
    huge_tree=True, # resolve_entities=False, remove_pis=True, no_network=True
)

XMLPARSER = etree.XMLParser(xml_parser_settings)
etree.set_default_parser(XMLPARSER)
```

After those statements you may use etree.parser with configured XMLPARSER. Beware of multithreading, though (https://lxml.de/1.3/api/lxml.etree-module.html#set_default_parser).

Adding resolve_entities, remove_pis and no_network keyword may (at least a bit) reduce your risk of parsing huge extarnal files, if they come from untrusted source.